# ¿Hay alguna forma de controlar el tamaño de las imágenes en los botones de xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, xamarin.ios

Soy nuevo en Xamarin Forms y quisiera saber como puedo controlar el tamaño de una imagen (icono) en un botón. Mi problema es que trato de añadir iconos a mis botones para que mi aplicación se vea mejor y mas amigable, pero me encuentro con el problema de que no puedo controlar el tamaño del icono (imagen) que le pongo al botón. Alguien me diría por favor como puedo controlar ese tamaño o cual es la forma correcta de ponerle iconos a los botones en Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Saludos Cristian, ¿has leído la documentación de Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Mucho, mas no logro encontrar una forma de controlar el tamaño de una imagen dentro de un botón

Comment: revisa: https://medium.com/@kevinle/buttons-with-image-and-stacklayout-in-xamarin-forms-apps-cc35c452f123 espero te sea de utilidad, si logras hacer funcionar lo que quieres, coloca la respuesta y de paso edita tu pregunta agrando el código que estás haciendo, los resultados que tienes y los que deseas :D

Comment: De acuerdo, voy a mirar el articulo que me pasaste ahí. Te lo agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

Pruebas con esto

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
        <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding NoConnection}" x:Name="ButtonStackLayout" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10" Padding="10,10,10,10" BackgroundColor="#E3E3E3">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="ButtonLabel" BackgroundColor="#E3E3E3" Text="Retry" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Image x:Name="ButtonImage" BackgroundColor="#E3E3E3" WidthRequest="24" Source="singin" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Esto creara un boton con una imagen en la parte derecha con el tamaño ajustado.

La información la tome de la pagina que mencionaron arriba: https://kevinle.medium.com/buttons-with-image-and-stacklayout-in-xamarin-forms-apps-cc35c452f123

Answer (score 0):

**En mi caso lo que use para mdificar el tamaño de algun imagebutton fue poner la propiedad HorizontalOptions="Center" seguido de mis HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="230"**

---

```
    <ImageButton Source="spr.png" HeightRequest="200"
                             WidthRequest="230" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
       BackgroundColor="White"  Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked_2" />
```